# Web API POST from fiddler returning 400 bad request, Your browser sent an invalid request

Tags: http-post, fiddler, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Fiddler to test my web api. GET, POST from localhost works, however when I deployed the API on IIS and test using the domain name, GET operations continue to work but not the POST. it returns a "400 Bad request. Your browser sent an invalid request."

here is a screenshot of my request. can someone shed me some light on what is wrong. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: where is the screenshot?

Answer (score 3):

**POST** and **PUT** requests need a **Content-Length header**, which your request is lacking. As you entered the request in the "Parsed" composer tab, Fiddler would normally automatically calculate and add it for you, unless you disabled "Fix Content-Lenght header" in the "Options" tab, which is what must have happened here.